# Wordpress get_results parsing the symbol "&"

Tags: wordpress

I have a strange Thing, where I do not know where the failure is.

```
$name = "Fast & Furious 8";

$res1 = $wpdb->prepare(
    "
        SELECT 
            * 
        FROM 
            wp_dbtable 
        WHERE 
            filmname = '%s' 
        LIMIT 1
    ", 
    $name
);

$res = $wpdb->get_results( $res1 );

foreach($res as $reseachG) {

}
```

I have a Problem with the Symbol `&`. For some reasons it does not pull anything out of my table, even if it should do this.

If I use instead of the variable the text it self, like this:

```
$res1 = $wpdb->prepare(
    "
        SELECT 
            * 
        FROM 
            wp_dbtable 
        WHERE 
            filmname = '%s' 
        LIMIT 1
    ", 
    "Fast & Furious 8"
);
```

it works. Also, other text inside the variable works well.

So it seems that `prepare`, or `get_results` does not accept this Symbol, or changes it. How can I solve it? I couldn't find any hint on the Internet.

It might not be a `PHP`-Problem, or a `My-SQL`-Problem, it might be a Problem of WordPress classes.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the output of the `echo "<pre>"; print_r($res1); echo "</pre>";` ? In addition, into your query you have the `'%s'`. You don't need that. The `%s` will automatically wrap the variable name with quotes.

Comment: I added an entry called `Fast & Furious 8` in a custom table and had no issues when I ran your first code to find that string.

Comment: @MerianosNikos the Outpu is: 

SELECT * FROM wp_dbtable WHERE filmname = 'Fast & Furious 8' LIMIT 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above is correct. The Problem was, that I pulled the text for the filmname out of the data base. He transformed the & into html-special-chars. So I had to run: `htmlspecialchars_decode($filmname);`. It was not easy to find, becase every print method printed the correct text.

I found an function on the Internet, which shows me hidden chars and every single real entiti. Maybe it will help some of you also:

```
function hexdump ($data, $htmloutput = true, $uppercase = false, $return = false){
// Init
$hexi   = '';
$ascii  = '';
$dump   = ($htmloutput === true) ? '<pre>' : '';
$offset = 0;
$len    = strlen($data);

// Upper or lower case hexadecimal
$x = ($uppercase === false) ? 'x' : 'X';

// Iterate string
for ($i = $j = 0; $i < $len; $i++)
{
    // Convert to hexidecimal
    $hexi .= sprintf("%02$x ", ord($data[$i]));

    // Replace non-viewable bytes with '.'
    if (ord($data[$i]) >= 32) {
        $ascii .= ($htmloutput === true) ?
                        htmlentities($data[$i]) :
                        $data[$i];
    } else {
        $ascii .= '.';
    }

    // Add extra column spacing
    if ($j === 7) {
        $hexi  .= ' ';
        $ascii .= ' ';
    }

    // Add row
    if (++$j === 16 || $i === $len - 1) {
        // Join the hexi / ascii output
        $dump .= sprintf("%04$x  %-49s  %s", $offset, $hexi, $ascii);

        // Reset vars
        $hexi   = $ascii = '';
        $offset += 16;
        $j      = 0;

        // Add newline            
        if ($i !== $len - 1) {
            $dump .= "\n";
        }
    }
}

// Finish dump
$dump .= $htmloutput === true ?
            '</pre>' :
            '';
$dump .= "\n";

// Output method
if ($return === false) {
    echo $dump;
} else {
    return $dump;
}
}
```

Which shows you the hexa-codes for each char and also every single space, line, special trasformed symbol, or line-braker. It helps to see the real data.

thx to all.